# Validating REST Request using RequestBodyAdvice

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to use RequestBodyAdvice in Spring Boot application to validate my JWT token and Device info. It works for POST method as it has @RequestBody in Controller however it is not working for GET method because there is no request body/payload. How to validate GET Services using RequestBodyAdvice, is there any other option?

Comment: Well, where exactly is the JWT token? You're (hopefully) sending it as a header in which case you can extract it from the `Request`

Comment: Yes Im sending it as part of Header, I want to handle it globally in one place before it hit the actual controller so thought of handling.

Comment: That's what [Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html)s are for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, GET request do not have request body. You should use interceptor or filter.